# Как выровнять кнопку справа

Tags: html, css

Как можно передвинуть красную кнопку так что бы было как на фото?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/YzwMqeE)

```css
.element-grid__element {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 282px;
}
.element-grid__like-button {
    background-image: url(../../../images/like-pic.svg);
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.element-grid__like-button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.element-grid__photo {
    width: 282px;
    height: 282px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.element-grid__text {
    font-family: 'Inter', ‘Arial’, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 88%;
}
.element-grid__text-container {
    margin: 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 25px 19px 31px;
    align-items: center;
}
.element-grid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px 18px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 282px);
    justify-content: center;
}

.popup-add {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.popup-add__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 430px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.popup-add__close {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/сlose-icon.svg) no-repeat center;
    width: 40.7px;
    height: 40.7px;
    right: -40.7px;
    top: -40.7px;
}

.popup-add__close:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.popup-add__title {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Inter', ‘Arial’, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
    color: black;
    width: 358px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 34px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .popup-add__title {
        max-width: 230px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
}

.popup-add__input {
    border: none;
    margin: 29.74px auto 0;
    padding-bottom: 13.3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    outline: none;
    color: #C4C4C4;
}

.popup-add__input:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top: 54px;
}

.popup-add__input:active {
    outline: 2px solid blue
}

@media screen and (max-width:750px) {
    .popup-add__input {
        width: auto;
    }
}

.popup-add__save-button {
    font-family: 'Inter', ‘Arial’, sans-serif;
    background: black;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 50.15px;
    width: 358px;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    margin: 48px auto 36.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-add__save-button:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .popup-add__save-button {
        width: 200px;
        height: 35px;
    }
}

.popup-add_active {
    display: block;
}

.element-grid__like-button_active {
    background-image: url(../images/likepic.PNG);
}

.element-grid__delite-button {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 4;
    /*position:absolute;*/
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
.elements {
    max-width: 882px;
    margin: 76px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.123a{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!--------
 
<button class="element-grid__delite-button" type="button"></button>
эту кнопку 
----------> 


<button class="profile__add-button" type="button"></button>
<section class="popup-add">
                <form class="popup-add__container" name="popup-add__container">
                    <button type="button" class="popup-add__close"></button>
                    <h2 class="popup__title">Новое Место</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="popup-add__input" placeholder="Название" id="name" />
                    <input type="text" class="popup-add__input" placeholder="Ссылка на картинку" id="link" />
                    <button type="submit" class="popup-add__save-button">Загрузить</button>
                </form>

            </section>
<section class="elements" aria-label="галерея">

                <ul class="element-grid">



                </ul>
            </section>

            <template id="photo-elements-template">
            <li class="element-grid__element">
            
                    <div class="123a">
                      <button class="element-grid__delite-button" type="button">
                    <img class="element-grid__photo" id="image" alt="" />
                </div>
                </div>
            

                <div class="element-grid__text-container">
                    <p class="element-grid__text"></p>

                    <button class="element-grid__like-button" type="button"></button>
                   

                </div>
            </li>
            </template>
```

Comment: @Vasily
на карточках слева есть красная кнопка. Но я я хочу ее передвинуть вправо , что бы было как на фотографии (образец). По идее эта кнопка должна удалять картинку , но почему то не удаляет (хотя скрипт удаления вроде прописал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте `position: relative` родительскому блоку, внутри него сделайте элемент, которому зададите `position: absolute`, тогда вы сможет манипулировать расположением `absolute` элемента с помощью css-свойств `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.card {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

button {
  --white: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  --black: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid var(--white);
  background-color: var(--black);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--white);
  transition: border-color 0.2s linear,
              background-color 0.2s linear,
              color 0.2s linear;
}

button:hover {
  color: var(--black);
  border-color: var(--black);
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.card button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vw;
  right: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <button>Helloooo</button>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/2000/1000">
</div>
```

Вариант с вашим кодом:

Я задал `position: relative` для **.element-grid__element**, `position: absolute` задал для **.element-grid__delite-button**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  let popupAdd = document.querySelector(".popup-add")
  let popupAddEditForm = document.querySelector(".profile__add-button")
  let popupAddClose = document.querySelector(".popup-add__close")
  let popupLoad = document.querySelector(".popup-add__save-button")

  popupLoad.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    addSubmitHandler()
  })

  function toggleAddPopup() {
    popupAdd.classList.toggle("popup-add_active")

  }

  function addForm() {
    toggleAddPopup()
  }


  popupAddEditForm.addEventListener("click", addForm)
  popupAddClose.addEventListener("click", toggleAddPopup)


  const initialCards = [{
      name: "Архыз",
      link: "https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/arkhyz.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "Челябинская область",
      link: "https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/chelyabinsk-oblast.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "Иваново",
      link: "https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/ivanovo.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "Камчатка",
      link: "https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kamchatka.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "Холмогорский район",
      link: "https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kholmogorsky-rayon.jpg"
    },
    {
      name: "Байкал",
      link: "https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/baikal.jpg"
    }
  ]

  const toggleLikeButton = (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle("element-grid__like-button_active")
  }

  const addPhotoElement = (caption, imageLink) => {
    const elementTemplate = document.querySelector("#photo-elements-template").content
    const photoElement = elementTemplate.cloneNode(true)
    photoElement.querySelector(".element-grid__photo").src = imageLink
    photoElement.querySelector(".element-grid__text").textContent = caption
    const photoElementsList = document.querySelector(".element-grid")

    photoElementsList.prepend(photoElement)

    document.querySelector(".element-grid__like-button").addEventListener("click", toggleLikeButton)

  }


  const addCards = (array) => {
    array.forEach((item) => {
      addPhotoElement(item.name, item.link)
    })
  }
  addCards(initialCards)



  const addSubmitHandler = (e) => {

    const newPhotoElementName = document.getElementById("name").value
    const newPhotoElementLink = document.getElementById("link").value

    addPhotoElement(newPhotoElementName, newPhotoElementLink)

    toggleAddPopup()
  }


})

const deleteCard = (e) => {
  e.target.closest(".element-grid__element").remove()
}
```

```css
.profile__add-button {
  display: none;
}

.element-grid__delite-button {
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.element-grid__element {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 282px;
  position: relative;
}

.element-grid__like-button {
  background-image: url(../../../images/like-pic.svg);
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

.element-grid__like-button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.element-grid__photo {
  width: 282px;
  height: 282px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-grid__text {
  font-family: 'Inter', ‘Arial’, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 29px;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 88%;
}

.element-grid__text-container {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 19px 31px;
  align-items: center;
}

.element-grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 18px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 282px);
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-add {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup-add__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 430px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.popup-add__close {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(../images/сlose-icon.svg) no-repeat center;
  width: 40.7px;
  height: 40.7px;
  right: -40.7px;
  top: -40.7px;
}

.popup-add__close:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.popup-add__title {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Inter', ‘Arial’, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 29px;
  color: black;
  width: 358px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 34px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .popup-add__title {
    max-width: 230px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

.popup-add__input {
  border: none;
  margin: 29.74px auto 0;
  padding-bottom: 13.3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 358px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  outline: none;
  color: #C4C4C4;
}

.popup-add__input:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top: 54px;
}

.popup-add__input:active {
  outline: 2px solid blue
}

@media screen and (max-width:750px) {
  .popup-add__input {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.popup-add__save-button {
  font-family: 'Inter', ‘Arial’, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 50.15px;
  width: 358px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  margin: 48px auto 36.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-add__save-button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .popup-add__save-button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
  }
}

.popup-add_active {
  display: block;
}

.element-grid__like-button_active {
  background-image: url(../images/likepic.PNG);
}

.element-grid__delite-button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 4;
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.elements {
  max-width: 882px;
  margin: 76px auto 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="profile__add-button" type="button"></button>
<section class="popup-add">
  <form class="popup-add__container" name="popup-add__container">
    <button type="button" class="popup-add__close"></button>
    <h2 class="popup__title">Новое Место</h2>
    <input type="text" class="popup-add__input" placeholder="Название" id="name" />
    <input type="text" class="popup-add__input" placeholder="Ссылка на картинку" id="link" />
    <button type="submit" class="popup-add__save-button">Загрузить</button>
  </form>

</section>
<section class="elements" aria-label="галерея">
  <ul class="element-grid">
  </ul>
</section>

<template id="photo-elements-template">
  <li class="element-grid__element">
    <button class="element-grid__delite-button" type="button"></button>
    <img class="element-grid__photo" id="image" alt="" />
    <div class="element-grid__text-container">
      <p class="element-grid__text"></p>
      <button class="element-grid__like-button" type="button"></button>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. Пропадают картинки (поглядите в моем пене , что не так ?(если снять коментирование  у свойства position absolute)

Comment: @Иваниванов а зачем вы в кнопку засунули картинку???? Тег button не одинарный тег, в инспекторе можете посмотреть, браузер делает из вашего <button> делает во так: <button></button>

Comment: @Иваниванов посмотрите на мою разметку: внутри карточки находится кнопка, а после кнопки идёт изображение

Comment: т.е и кнопке и изображению задаю абсолютное позиционирование , а 123a  див я удаляю ?

Comment: @Иваниванов это уже решайте сами, тут я задал изображению позиционирование абсолютное, потому что хотел, чтобы картинка была на всю высоту и ширину родительского контейнера

Comment: Не думал , что споткнусь на таком , но не могу сделать. Попробовал так как написал выше - результат из массива не стали грузиться картинки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111098/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: Cпасибо , все заработало

Answer (score 2):

Одним из самых простых способов для того что бы выровнять какой либо элемент по правому краю будет добавить ему свойство [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) со значением "right":

```
.element-grid__delite-button {
    float: right;
}
```

Как я понял, Вы хотите что бы кнопка располагалась поверх изображения, в этом случае стоит воспользоваться абсолютным позиционированием:

```
.element-grid__element {
    position: relative;
}

.element-grid__delite-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Как можно наблюдать выше я задал обертке li относительную позицию, а кнопке абсолютную, выровняв ее с правого края.

*Всвязи с существенным количеством ошибок в Вашем примере я сделал его упрощенную версию, где вынес картинку из элемента button*:

```css
img {
  width: auto; 
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.element-grid__element {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 282px;
  height: 282px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.element-grid__delite-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="element-grid__element">
   <img class="element-grid__photo" src="https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kholmogorsky-rayon.jpg"/>
   <button class="element-grid__delite-button" type="button"></button>
</li>

<li class="element-grid__element">
   <img class="element-grid__photo" src="https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/baikal.jpg"/>
   <button class="element-grid__delite-button" type="button"></button>
</li>
```

Если же Вам нужно выровнять элементы без наложения одного на другой, то
Вы можете воспользоваться [возможностями выравнивая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2_Flex_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5) во [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex), раз уж Вы все равно его уже используете.

Comment: Почему то у меня если я так попытался сделать все слетает. Можете свой кодпен выложить ? НЕ могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: У меня да , не то совсем

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать кнопке абсолютное позиционирование, относительно дива, содержащего её

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

div button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Тоже слетело... (может быть что то в скрипте для этой кнопки проблема ?)

Comment: @Иваниванов, а что за скрипт?

Comment: ну что код что бы красная кнопка удаляла картинку

Comment: тогда ещё вопрос: удаляла картинку из разметки, или картинка появляется там из какого-нибудь объекта или массива?

Comment: Картинка из массива